# How can I use a value in the object column as a wherekey?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to pick up all the objects which equal a certain date and match a certain value, but I am unsure how to do that. I need to get the object which date contains a 10 or higher, so in this case it would pick up the object since one or both have a number greater than 10.

This is the Number column, it is of type "Object"

```
{"Tue":[1, 0],
"Wed":[1]
}
```

ios code:

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "Animal")
 //I don't know which wherekey to use
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if(error == nil){
            print(objects)

            for object in objects!{
              print(object)
            }
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is of type [String: [Int]]:

```
let dict: [String: [Int]] = ["Tue": [1, 0], "Wed":[1]]
let filtered = dict.filter{ $0.1.filter{ $0 == 0 }.count > 0 }
print(filtered) // "Tue": [1, 0]
```

Comment: So I updated my question, and I just need to return the objects where the Int for each string (`[String: [Int]]`) contains at least one 0. So in the question, Wed would not show up, but Tue would.

Comment: Corrected, it should be $0 == 0 (not $0 = 0, this is an assignment and $0 is immutable)